# RESTful API deleting invalid data

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express

```
router.delete('/:id', function(req, res){
    user.remove({

        _id: req.params.id 

    }, function(err, users) {

        if(err) {
            res.status(404).send({
                message: "Invalid User",
                data: []    
            });

        } else {
            res.status(200).send({
                message: "User deleted",
                data: []
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I tried to implement the DELETE endpoint for my RESTful API.
It successfully deletes an existing data when I test it on postman,
but when I try to delete an invalid data, it still gives me a delete message
with a response status of 200.

What mistake am I making?

Answer (score 0):

That right when you delete an not exist data the code work fine .

But you can check in users values it return `nMatched` if working in mongodb.
and for all database they contain this type of flag (here flag means 'nMatched' field in users object , you can check by printing `users` object ). for mongodb  they contains values in `0` or `1`

Can you something like this.

```
function(err, users) {

        if(err) {
            res.status(404).send({
                message: "Invalid User",
                data: []    
            });

        } else if (users.nMatched === 0) {

            res.status(400).send({
                message: "User not exist deleted",
                data: []
            });
        } else {
            res.status(200).send({
              message: "User deleted",
              data: []
             });
           }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean "and for all database they contain this type of flag . for mongodb they contains values in 0 or 1"

Comment: Flag means  you have `users` object which return after database call , it will contains some key value which have data whether anything was deleted . In case of mongodb you can access it  like this `users.nMatched`  . Just print users you will get all status flag.

Comment: Then what is the different between "Invalid User" and "User not exist deleted" ?

Comment: Also, it keeps giving me "User deleted" when I keep requesting delete for the same user. Isn't supposed to give me "User deleted" only on the first call?

Comment: "Invalid User" means in above code `if any error comes in query`  and "User not exist deleted" means the `data is not there in database`.  Is that give your answer.

Comment: Sorry, it still gives me "User Deleted" when I try to delete an invalid user.

Comment: Print `users` and add result in comments .